# Calling Win32 Dll from C# on Windows Server 2012

Tags: pinvoke, windows-server-2012

I have an application that calls to a Win32 Dll written in Delphi.  My application is developed in C# and running under IIS.  I can successfully call the Delphi Dll on every Windows release from Server 2003 upwards with the exception of Windows Server 2012.  The call to the external method doesn't return any errors nor is there anything in the error log. It just never returns any data.

In my C# I declare:

```
[DllImport("MyTest.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
       CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern void Encrypt(string szPlainText, StringBuilder szCipherText);
```

I then call the function with the following:

```
StringBuilder encText = new StringBuilder(128);
StringBuilder plainString = new StringBuilder("test");

Encrypt(plainString.ToString(), encText);
```

Has something changed in WinServer 2012 that would stop this from working?

The Delphi Code that I have access to looks like:

```
procedure Encrypt(szPlainText: PChar; szCipherText : PChar) ; stdcall ; export;
var
   sTemp : String ;
   sPlainText : String ;
   cipher : TCipher ;

 begin
   cipher := TLogixCipher.Create ;
   sPlainText := szPlainText ;

   sTemp  := cipher.Encrypt(sPlainText ) ;
   StrPCopy(szCipherText,sTemp);    
   FreeAndNil(cipher) ;
 end;
```

Comment: "Anything changed?": I've not heard anything. If you have the symbols for the Delphi component you could enable native debugging and step through the P/Invoke call.

Comment: Please show the Delphi function's declaration. Also, the C# calling code you present is incomplete. Please show more.

Comment: I don't have access to the Delphi function at the moment. It's not something I developed

Comment: OK, without that, we are going to have to rely on a little guesswork. I'm assuming that `szPlainText` is `PWideChar` and an input parameter. So the function won't modify it. And I also assume that `szCipherText` is also `PWideChar`, and that the function does modify it. And clearly the caller must allocate the buffer, and so need to know how large a buffer to make. Those are the assumptions I made in order to write my answer. Are they accurate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** This answer was written to match the original version of the question. Since it was written the question was changed to incorporate the changes suggested below.

---

The p/invoke declaration is probably wrong for a start. The first parameter is an input parameter (I presume) and so should be declared as string. I'd declare the p/invoke like this:

```
public static extern void Encrypt(
    string szPlainText, 
    StringBuilder szCipherText
);
```

This won't really matter, but there's little point in marshalling the plain text back to the managed code when the function returns since the plain text won't have changed.

The second issue is that you need to allocate the buffer in the `szCipherText` parameter before calling.

So, suppose that you knew that the buffer needed to be of length 100, you would write it like this:

```
StringBuilder CipherText = new StringBuilder(100);
Encrypt(PlainText, CipherText);
```

Perhaps the mechanism for this function is that the cipher text is the same length and the plain text. In which case your call would be:

```
StringBuilder CipherText = new StringBuilder(PlainText.Length);
Encrypt(PlainText, CipherText);
```

You note that the function you call does not return any errors. That's not very surprising since there is no mechanism for it to do so.

Why has your code started mis-behaving now? You've switch operating system and that appears to have induced a change. But all that means is that your code has always been wrong, and that you just got away with it before now. And the new version of the OS that you are using happens to behave differently with your incorrect code.

---

After your various updates, the code in the question is now correct. Which leads me to suspect that the Delphi code is indeed returning the empty string. In which case the logical conclusion is that `cipher.Encrypt` returns the empty string. Try replacing the Delphi code with this function to test the interface:

```
procedure Encrypt(szPlainText: PChar; szCipherText: PChar); stdcall;
begin
  StrPCopy(szCipherText, szPlainText);    
end;
```

Comment: I've made the changes you suggested but there has been no difference. This code has been deployed on many non Server 2012 machines without issue. I've tried it on 2 Server 2012 machines in totally different environments without success which has me thinking there is something different from previous windows Versions.

Comment: You need to know more about your environment than you have told us yet. You have not given a detailed spec of the interface and so I have had to make guesses. Are you 100% sure you aren't running under 64 bit? And try to get some diagnostics. Does the C# code even reach the call to Encrypt? If you have a function that behaves as I outline in my comment to the question, the code in my answer is how you call it.

Comment: It is running in 64bit mode, the Delphi dll is also 64bit.  It definitely reaches the call, I've log statements either side of it.

Comment: OK, that's something. The bottom line though is that your code will be wrong, at one end or another. And the code will always have been wrong. You just got lucky before.

Comment: I've gotten the Delphi declaration: procedure Encrypt(szPlainText: PChar; szCipherText : PChar) ; stdcall ; export;  I've also updated my original code

Comment: OK, are you really passing the empty string as your plain text?

Comment: Well, it looks like I've now debugged all the errors in your question. Next step is to debug the code. I suggest that you now show the Delphi code. I am now sceptical of what you say though because the code in your original question is totally different from that in the question now. How can we believe what you say? You must take more care in future. Be accurate.

Comment: The Delphi code looks fine, and matches the C# code. The latest C# code in your question does not compile do you know. You cannot pass a `StringBuilder` to a `string` parameter. And `plainString` is `StringBuilder`. At this point you are confused, and so am I. What you really should do is write a small simple SSCCE. All the confusion stems from the fact that you have not done that yet.

Comment: My bad, that's from making the edits in here. I forgot to do a ToString() on my stringbuilder.  I've actually tried a 32 bit version of the Delphi DLL and changed my IIS apppool to run in 32bit mode and it works fine. However I prefer to run in 64bit mode.

Comment: Well, there's nothing wrong with the code in the question as it stands now.

Comment: I'm thinking the same, I'm really puzzled. It basically only fails now on Windows Server 2012 running the IIS App Pool in 64bit mode.

Comment: We've added debugging right the way through. The call to Encrypt is definitely returning an empty string. We've hardcoded return values and verified that the inputs are being received so we are sure the interface is now correct.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Perhaps you might care to vote for my answer and consider accepting it. I note that you've voted only once and not accepted that much. It's important to give back to the community. I know you still have a problem, but my help has clearly led you to the root of the problem.

Comment: Thank you. I also respectfully suggest that you find a little time to review your other questions and see if you can vote on good answers, and accept the best ones. Thank you! And well done for working with me helpfully in this question.